# Detect USB-C to 3.5 mm jack adapter as headphone even though headphone is not connected/plugged into adapter

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I'm listening to `AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification` for audio route change using NotificationCenter.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(handleRouteChange),
                                       name: AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification,
                                       object: nil)
```

Based on the notification data we decide if plugged in device is headphone or not by using this function:

```
@objc private func handleRouteChange(notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
              let reasonValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? UInt,
              let reason = AVAudioSession.RouteChangeReason(rawValue: reasonValue) else {
                  return
              }

        switch reason {
        case .newDeviceAvailable:
            if hasHeadphones(in: session.currentRoute) {
                // Heaphone Logic
            } else {
               // Speaker logic
            }
        case .oldDeviceUnavailable:
            if !hasHeadphones(in: session.currentRoute) {
                // Speaker logic
            }
        case .override:
            if !hasHeadphones(in: session.currentRoute) {
                // Speaker logic
            }
        default:()
        }
    }
    
    func hasHeadphones(in routeDescription: AVAudioSessionRouteDescription) -> Bool {
        return !routeDescription.outputs.filter({$0.portType == .headphones}).isEmpty
    }
```

I'm coming across the issue that if the headphone is not plugged into the adapter, `routeDescription.outputs` array still has one element inside. This element has `portType` of `.headphones` which means that the headphone is connected even though headphone is not connected to adapter.

Not advertising but I'm using [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09GYRH6YM) adapter for my iPad.

Version: iPad Pro(12.9 Inch) 5th gen

iOS Version: 15.6.1

Is this an expected result or is there any possible workaround for this issue?